# Get the name of one column by index in R

Tags: r

Imagine the following dataframe df:

```
name <- c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria")
age <- c(23, 41, 32)
df <- data.frame(name, age)
```

I want to be able to get the name of a column using its index.

If I try and get the names of multiple columns, it is fine:

```
colnames(df[,c(1,2)])
[1] "name" "age"
```

However, when I try to get only one, say the first, it is not working as I would expect:

```
colnames(df[,1])
NULL
```

What is that and how can I get the name of my first column "name"?

Comment: matrix subsetting by `[` strips the object of its name, so either `colnames(df)[1]` or `colnames(df[1])` will work.  `colnames(df[,1])` won't.

Comment: Your approach will work if you set `drop` to `FALSE`, i.e. `colnames(df[, 1, drop = FALSE])`. See `?Extract` for the details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

simply

```
colnames(df)[1]
[1] "name"
```

or

```
colnames(df[1])
[1] "name"
```

or

```
names(df[1])
  [1] "name"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enable `drop = FALSE`

```
> colnames(df[,1,drop = FALSE])
[1] "name"
```

or

```
> colnames(df[1])              
[1] "name"
```